# Node JS Batch Get on Redis Keys

Tags: node.js, caching, redis

I want to get a lot of key/ values stored on Redis at once, using a batch request. 
I am using the node js redis client. The idea is to make a get request on multiple keys asynchronously, any way to do this?
I checked the batch function in node js Redis client, from what I understood it's useful in the case if you want to get all the elements of a hash at once but not the data of different keys at once in async mode.

what I am trying to do is reading all the table to pick specific key / values based on an attribute of the value (timestamp)

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `MGET`, per the [docs](https://redis.io/commands/mget):

> ```
> redis> SET key1 "Hello"
> "OK"
> redis> SET key2 "World"
> "OK"
> redis> MGET key1 key2 nonexisting
> 1) "Hello"
> 2) "World"
> 3) (nil)
> ```

If you're using the [redis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis) package, it should look like this:

```
client.mget(["key1", "key2", "nonexisting"], (err, val) => {
  console.log(val); //["Hello", "World", null]
});
```

Comment: not exactly, what I am trying to do is reading all the table to pick specific key / values based on an attribute of the value (timestamp)

Comment: @Tar You'll have to fetch all keys using `KEYS *` or repeated `SCAN` calls followed by `MGET`. I don't think Redis supports applying logic against all values and picking ones that pass the test - that's the kind of thing you do in code or db queries.

Comment: yes, the logic will be done in the code, I am only querying Redis to fetch data, is it possible to do a SCAN on multiple keys asynchronously let's say scanning 10 keys at a time ?

Comment: @Tar all redis commands are necessarily asynchronous to begin with. each `SCAN` requires the cursor returned by the previous, so I don't believe you can easily do bulk parallel processing that way. if you'd like to minimize time taken, using one `KEYS` with the correct pattern followed by an `MGET` will take the minimum travel time for all the data to get to your process, but will take up much more memory during processing and will block the redis server while it fetches all the matching keys.

Comment: @Tar with SCAN you'll need to fire off many more individual commands to redis but both you and the server can process data one chunk at a time, which will cause a much lower processing spike but probably take more time